# Series name of a book about an outcast ex-rebellion general against a colony of planets with FTL capabilities

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a book a while ago and I'm trying to remember its name.

The book was about an outcast who used to be the general of a rebellion against a colony of planets. These planets had faster than light capabilities using radioactive tracers as pathways.

The main character, the ex general, finds an abundance of this radioactive material on this hostile, desolate planet he was banned to. He also finds this silver water that implants the consciousness of the previous inhabitants into humans.

Comment: Is it a single book, or a series of books?

Comment: Is there any more information you can add?  Like how long ago you read this, anything about the cover, names of any characters?  The more information you can give us the more chance we have of helping you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like [*Hellhole*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8734164-hellhole) by Brian Herbert and Kevin J Anderson.

From the blurb on the linked site:

> Only the most desperate colonists dare to make a new home on Hellhole. Reeling from a recent asteroid impact, tortured with horrific storms, tornadoes, hurricanes, earthquakes, and churning volcanic eruptions, the planet is a dumping ground for undesirables, misfits, and charlatans…but also a haven for dreamers and independent pioneers.
>
> Against all odds, an exiled general named Adolphus has turned Hellhole into a place of real opportunity for the desperate colonists who call the planet their home. While the colonists are hard at work developing the planet, General Adolphus secretly builds alliances with the leaders of the other Deep Zone worlds, forming a clandestine coalition against the tyrannical, fossilized government responsible for their exile.

From [one of the (less favourable) reviews](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/402053951?book_show_action=false&from_review_page=1) at the same linked site:

> One guy dies after he falls into the Slickwaer Lake and yet no one else who jumped in suffered the same fate, they were all allowed to get out and are levitated out by the powerful aliens in the soup.

There are two sequels to the first book:  *Hellhole Awakenings* and *Hellhole Inferno*.

Comment: This is definitely the book, thank you so much.

Comment: @YouGoUpIGoDown Thanks for the feedback, you can accept the answer by ticking it to make it clear this is the correct book series.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I never really used this site before.